# Add Layers to GeoServer with REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to add a new layer to GeoServer programmatically, So at first i have added a new `workspace` and then a new `datastores`, so far eveything is good, but when i'm trying to add a new layer i get error 500 which is:

```
Cannot cast org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LayerInfoImpl to org.geoserver.catalog.FeatureTypeInfo
```

What i'm doing is that i'm using below code:

```
<layer>
<name>Shahrestan</name>
<type>VECTOR</type>
<defaultStyle>
<name>polygon</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:1024/geoserver/rest/styles/polygon.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</defaultStyle>
<resource class="featureType">
<name>cite:Shahrestan</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:1024/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/datastores/kamal/featuretypes/Shahrestan.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</resource>
<attribution>
<logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
<logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
</attribution>
</layer>
```

And send it to the url below:

```
http://localhost:1024/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/datastores/kamal/featuretypes
```

Please note that i have already created a new layer using geoserver ui, and then i went through the geoserver rest index to get the xml codes

```
http://localhost:1024/geoserver/rest
```

But still i'm getting error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are sending a `LayerInfo` representation to an endpoint that expects a `FeatureTypeInfo` representation. If you make a request to the endpoint it will show you what is expected, for example do a GET on

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/taz_shapes/featuretypes/tasmania_roads.xml
```

You get this back (note how the enclosing tag is `FeatureType`):

```
<featureType>
<name>tasmania_roads</name>
<nativeName>tasmania_roads</nativeName>
<namespace>
<name>topp</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/topp.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</namespace>
<title>Tasmania roads</title>
<abstract>Main Tasmania roads</abstract>
<keywords>
<string>Roads</string>
<string>Tasmania</string>
</keywords>
<nativeCRS>
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", DATUM["WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]]
</nativeCRS>
<srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
<nativeBoundingBox>
<minx>145.19754</minx>
<maxx>148.27298000000002</maxx>
<miny>-43.423512</miny>
<maxy>-40.852802</maxy>
<crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
</nativeBoundingBox>
<latLonBoundingBox>
<minx>145.19754</minx>
<maxx>148.27298000000002</maxx>
<miny>-43.423512</miny>
<maxy>-40.852802</maxy>
<crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
</latLonBoundingBox>
<projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<metadata>
<entry key="kml.regionateFeatureLimit">10</entry>
<entry key="cacheAgeMax">3600</entry>
<entry key="cachingEnabled">true</entry>
<entry key="indexingEnabled">false</entry>
<entry key="dirName">tasmania_roads</entry>
</metadata>
<store class="dataStore">
<name>topp:taz_shapes</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/taz_shapes.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</store>
<maxFeatures>0</maxFeatures>
<numDecimals>0</numDecimals>
<overridingServiceSRS>false</overridingServiceSRS>
<skipNumberMatched>false</skipNumberMatched>
<circularArcPresent>false</circularArcPresent>
<attributes>
<attribute>
<name>the_geom</name>
<minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
<maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
<nillable>true</nillable>
<binding>org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString</binding>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>TYPE</name>
<minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
<maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
<nillable>true</nillable>
<binding>java.lang.String</binding>
<length>7</length>
</attribute>
</attributes>
</featureType>
```

You almost certainly need to be hitting `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/topp:tasmania_roads.xml` (for example) which returns (starting with a `Layer` tag):

```
<layer>
<name>tasmania_roads</name>
<path>/</path>
<type>VECTOR</type>
<defaultStyle>
<name>simple_roads</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/simple_roads.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</defaultStyle>
<resource class="featureType">
<name>topp:tasmania_roads</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/taz_shapes/featuretypes/tasmania_roads.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</resource>
<attribution>
<logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
<logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
</attribution>
</layer>
```